# Way of register non invoked javascript classes

Tags: javascript, node.js, sockets, invoke

I have some problems, I'm currently developing a web socket game in Javascript (using Node.js) and I will need to register a lot of protocol messages (about 500+), each message have a unique id/key, and I search a way to dynamically register (at runtime) these message into a key constructor dictionary

I was searching about annotations and reflection but with these options I need to invoke my classes before, do somebody have a solution ?

I know that in Java we do this trick :

```
Set<Method> methodsAnnotatedWith = new Reflections("my.package", new MethodAnnotationsScanner()).getMethodsAnnotatedWith(SomeAnnotation.class);
```

Is there a way in Javascript / Typescript ?

Comment: Hi there! How do you "protocol messages" look in JS? Is it an array? If so, how do the elements look?

Comment: My protocol message will look as a class with a key property, and a serialize / deserialize functions